# How to rotate 3D Japanese characters from its center axis?

Tags: three.js

I am certain this question gets asked frequently and had the time to check some answers but I am still unable to make the meshes rotate by its center.

The file loads a Japanese font to display three words and rotates each when the frame is refreshed. Each word rotates from its starting point, being the first character. I'm looking for the axis to be the center of the word.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">


  <title>3js</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;">

<script src="three.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var camera, scene, renderer

  var material, spotlight

  var text1, text2, text3, pivot

  var texts = []

  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0

  var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2
  var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2

  loadFont()
  init()
  animate()

  function init() {

    // Create camera

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000)
    camera.position.z = 50

    // Create scene

    scene = new THREE.Scene()

    // Create material

    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0xFF97A3,
      emissive: 0xFF97A3
    })

    // Create and add light

    spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFF97A3)
    spotlight.position.set(30, 60, 60)
    scene.add(spotlight)

    // Renderer

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
    renderer.setClearColor(0x1a1a1a)
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

    // Responsive on window resize

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    // Store x and y position on mouse movement

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false)

  }

  function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )

  }

  function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

    mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) * 0.02
    mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) * 0.02

  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate )

    texts.forEach(updateMeshes)

    render()
  }

  function render () {

     // Adjust camera's position based on mouse x and y position

    camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.01
    camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * 0.01

    camera.lookAt(scene.position)

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
  }

  function updateMeshes(mesh) {

    var randomSpeed = Math.random() * ( 0.0015 - 0.0001 ) + 0.001

    mesh.rotation.x += randomSpeed
    mesh.rotation.y += randomSpeed
    mesh.updateMatrix()

  }

  /* HELPERS */

  // Settings
  var height = 2,
        size = 10,
        curveSegments = 0,
        bevelThickness = 0,
        bevelSize = 0,
        bevelSegments = 3,
        bevelEnabled = true,
        font = undefined

  // Load js font file
  function loadFont() {
    var loader = new THREE.FontLoader()
    loader.load('songti_sc_bold.typeface.js', function (res) {
      font = res
      createText()
    })
  }

  // Creates text 3D objects with previous settings
  function createText() {
    textGeo1 = new THREE.TextGeometry( '耐久', {
      font: font,
      size: size,
      height: height,
      curveSegments:curveSegments,
      weight: "normal",
      bevelThickness:bevelThickness,
      bevelSize:bevelSize,
      bevelSegments:bevelSegments,
      bevelEnabled:bevelEnabled
    })

    textGeo2 = new THREE.TextGeometry('決意', {
      font: font,
      size: size,
      height: height,
      curveSegments: curveSegments,
      weight: "normal",
      bevelThickness: bevelThickness,
      bevelSize: bevelSize,
      bevelSegments: bevelSegments,
      bevelEnabled: bevelEnabled
    })

    textGeo3 = new THREE.TextGeometry('愛', {
      font: font,
      size: size,
      height: height,
      curveSegments: curveSegments,
      weight: "normal",
      bevelThickness: bevelThickness,
      bevelSize: bevelSize,
      bevelSegments: bevelSegments,
      bevelEnabled: bevelEnabled
    })

    var text1 = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo1, material)
    var text2 = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo2, material)
    var text3 = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo3, material)

    // Position text1 on screen

    text1.position.x = 1
    text1.position.y = 1
    text1.position.z = 1

    // Initial text1 rotation

    text1.rotation.x = 0
    text1.rotation.y = 0.4
    text1.rotation.z = 0.4

    // Position text2 on screen

    text2.position.x = -15
    text2.position.y = -35
    text2.position.z = -100

    // Initial text2 rotation

    text2.rotation.x = 0
    text2.rotation.y = 0
    text2.rotation.z = 0

    // Position text3 on screen

    text3.position.x = 30
    text3.position.y = -25
    text3.position.z = -20

    // Initial text3 rotation

    text3.rotation.x = 30
    text3.rotation.y = -25
    text3.rotation.z = -20

    scene.add(text1)
    scene.add(text2)
    scene.add(text3)

    texts.push(text1)
    texts.push(text2)
    texts.push(text3)
  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you want to grab the files, I have the code on github: https://github.com/marioecg/kanjis-3JS

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to find how wide each character is by its bounding box. Add spacing between the characters, and you have the total width of the word. From there, you must calculate the positions of the characters relative to the overall width of the word. Add these characters to a [`THREE.Group`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Group), add the group to the scene, and rotate the group. Give that a shot, and let us know if you run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the approach! @TheJim01, I think I solved it by adding .center() after creating each text geometry. Does your solution have the same outcome, or what's the difference?

Comment: I think I missed the mark a bit--my approach was aimed at horizontal multi-character words, and rotating the full word, not the individual characters. `.center()` can be expensive because it touches every vertex of a mesh.

Comment: I see @TheJim01, thank you!

Comment: I can assure you that no one has ever asked how to specifically rotate **japanese** characters, this is a first.

Comment: @pailhead I'm glad to be first haha!